# Run script when an option from a dropdown menu is selected

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

As the title says, the script that i have is a calculator, and works perfect, but i want it to use it only on one specific option, which can be selected from a dropdown menu. I have a page called EditEntry.php, where you can edit stuff from database. When selecting an option from a dropdown menu, i want the script to run, otherwise works all the time.
This is the calculator script.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function MM_findObj(n, d) { //v4.01
var p,i,x;  if(!d) d=document; if((p=n.indexOf("?"))>0&&parent.frames.length) {
d=parent.frames[n.substring(p+1)].document; n=n.substring(0,p);}
if(!(x=d[n])&&d.all) x=d.all[n]; for (i=0;!x&&i<d.forms.length;i++) x=d.forms[i][n];
for(i=0;!x&&d.layers&&i<d.layers.length;i++) x=MM_findObj(n,d.layers[i].document);
if(!x && d.getElementById) x=d.getElementById(n); return x;
}

function KW_getVal(o){ //v1.2
var retVal="0";if (o.type=="select-one")
{retVal=(o.selectedIndex==-1)?0:o.options[o.selectedIndex].value;}
else if (o.length>1){for (var i=0;i<o.length;i++) if (o[i].checked) retVal=o[i].value;
} else if (o.type=="checkbox") {retVal=(o.checked)?o.value:0;} else {
retVal=Number(o.value)}return parseFloat(retVal);
}

function KW_calcForm() { //v1.2
var str="",a=KW_calcForm.arguments; for (var i=3;i<a.length;i++)
str+=(a[i].indexOf("#")==-1)?a[i]:KW_getVal(MM_findObj(a[i].substring(1)));
t=Math.round(a[1]*eval(str))/a[1];tS=t.toString();if(a[2]>0){tSp=tS.indexOf(".");
if(tSp==-1) tS+=".";tSp=tS.indexOf(".");while(tSp!=(tS.length-1-a[2])){tS+="0";
tSp=tS.indexOf(".");}} MM_findObj(a[0]).value=tS;
}
function KW_calcForm() { //v1.2
var str="",a=KW_calcForm.arguments; for (var i=3;i<a.length;i++)
str+=(a[i].indexOf("#")==-1)?a[i]:KW_getVal(MM_findObj(a[i].substring(1)));
t=Math.round(a[1]*eval(str))/a[1];tS=t.toString();if(a[2]>0){tSp=tS.indexOf(".");
if(tSp==-1) tS+=".";tSp=tS.indexOf(".");while(tSp!=(tS.length-1-a[2])){tS+="0";
tSp=tS.indexOf(".");}} MM_findObj(a[0]).value=tS;
}
</script>
```

This is the dropdown menu.

```
<td><select name="Operator">
    <option value="" <?php if (!(strcmp("", htmlentities($row_Recordset1['Operator'], ENT_COMPAT, 'utf-8')))) {echo "selected=\"selected\"";} ?>></option>
    <option value="Dani" <?php if (!(strcmp("Dani", htmlentities($row_Recordset1['Operator'], ENT_COMPAT, 'utf-8')))) {echo "selected=\"selected\"";} ?>>Dani</option>
    <option value="Costi" <?php if (!(strcmp("Costi", htmlentities($row_Recordset1['Operator'], ENT_COMPAT, 'utf-8')))) {echo "selected=\"selected\"";} ?>>Costi</option>
    <option value="Ioni" <?php if (!(strcmp("Ioni", htmlentities($row_Recordset1['Operator'], ENT_COMPAT, 'utf-8')))) {echo "selected=\"selected\"";} ?>>Ioni</option>
    <option value="Cristina" <?php if (!(strcmp("Cristina", htmlentities($row_Recordset1['Operator'], ENT_COMPAT, 'utf-8')))) {echo "selected=\"selected\"";} ?>>Cristina</option>
    <option value="Alex" <?php if (!(strcmp("Alex", htmlentities($row_Recordset1['Operator'], ENT_COMPAT, 'utf-8')))) {echo "selected=\"selected\"";} ?>>Alex</option>
    <option value="Roland" <?php if (!(strcmp("Roland", htmlentities($row_Recordset1['Operator'], ENT_COMPAT, 'utf-8')))) {echo "selected=\"selected\"";} ?>>Roland</option>
  </select></td>
```

And this is where the calculator kicks in.

```
<td><input name="PretNoi" type="text" onclick="KW_calcForm('PretNoi',100,-1,'0.7','*','(','#PretFirma','-','#PretPiesa',')')" value="<?php echo htmlentities($row_Recordset1['PretNoi'], ENT_COMPAT, 'utf-8'); ?>" size="32"/></td>
```

I have tried many things, but none work, i tried adding jQuery options at the start of the script, didint work. I tried adding a "php if" in the  but without success. I thought that adding an "if" option somewhere, the calculator would start, only when "Roland" is selected. I need some help with this, again, can the calculator work ONLY when "Roland" option is selected? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Try the jQuery `.change()` method](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=on%20select%20change%20jquery):

> Description: Bind an event handler to the "change" JavaScript event, or trigger that event on an element.

```
$("select[name='Operator']").change(function(){
    var value = $(this).val();
    if(value == "Roland"){
        // Do your function here
    } else return false;
});
```

Comment: I tried adding this at the begining of the script $("select[name='Operator']").change(function(){
    var value = $(this).val();
    if(value == "Roland"){ SCRIPT HERE } else return false;
}); , but doesnt work at all

Comment: Have you included *jQuery*?

Comment: how do i include jQuery?

Comment: See [https://jquery.com/](https://jquery.com/)... you can either download the script and add it to your web page or include it from the CDN by adding `<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` in the header of your page...

Comment: Still not working, i dont know what im doing wrong. i can send you the whole page for you to test if you want